# How do I create a WT project in MSVC?

Tags: c++, project, c-preprocessor, wt, compiler-options

If anyone has used WT successfully with MSVC (mine is 2005), could you please provide some details on how this can be done?
I have installed WT fine , then ran some examples. The problems begin when I try to create a project of my own, as simple as hello.C. I get a thousand compiler errors like this one :

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\cstdio(25) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'

Possibly some project tuning is required, which I could not figure out, despite trying for many hours...Any help will be appreciated.

[Edit] WT is the [Witty (webtoolkit.eu)](http://webtoolkit.eu)

Comment: Do you mean [webtoolkit](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/internet/browsercontrol/article.php/c15275/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after searching and googling around for some days , it seems that using CMake is a must in order to build a WT project. [This page](http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/wiki/wt/Using_CMake) explains the procedure. Hopefully it will save you some time.

Comment: The page is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a random stab: Try renaming your file "hello.cpp".  MSVC compiles .c files as C by default, not C++.

The first result for WT I found via google is the one Jason D linked.  It is a C++ library, not a C library.

If this doesn't help, please provide more info, including what "WT" stands for, and some of your short sample code.